# How to get Active (focused) slickgrid?

Tags: slickgrid

[image]

I have two slickgrid and one delete button,
When i click on delete,i want focused grid so that i will delete items.

**How to get focused grid ?**

This is what i have done so far....

```
function deleteRow(e, args){

 //code to delete items from "grid"
 var selectedrows = grid.getSelectedRows();  
 var len = selectedrows.length;
        var itemNo = "";
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
        {                        
           var data = grid.getData().getItem(selectedrows[i]);  
           dataView.deleteItem(data.id);
           itemNo =data.id;
           var url = "delete_Item_Master?itemNo="+itemNo;
            $.get(url, {itemNo : itemNo},function(data) {
                    location.reload(true);
            }); 

        }
 //code to delete items from "metalGrid"    
 var metalSelectedrows = metalGrid.getSelectedRows();  
 var mlen = metalSelectedrows.length;
     var itemNo = "";
        for(var i=0;i<mlen;i++)
        {     

           var mData = metalGrid.getData().getItem(metalSelectedrows[i]); 
           meyalDataView.deleteItem(mData.id); 
          itemNo =mData.id;
            var url = "delete_subItem?itemNo="+itemNo;
            $.get(url, {itemNo : itemNo},function(data) {
                    location.reload(true);
            }); 
        }
}
```

But this code delete items from both grid..

Answer (score 0):

I think that the *correct* way to do this is to write your own [selection model](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Handling-selection). It should be a Singleton, and two grids should interact with it. It should know which grid was last active.

But you need to ask yourself is that behaviour is good. What if user will delete an item from *another* grid - because there's only one button. IMHO every grid should have it's own button. And I work for an ERP company where we got that dillemas everyday ;)